# MMYYYY compare to YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have dates stored as chars in db (i know, but its not my db nor my idea..).

One of the dates is stored as MMYYYY (012016,022016...) and the second one is stored as YYYYMMDD (20160101,20160202...).

Is there a way to compare those dates? I need to take one date and select all of the second dates which are at least one year older then the first one...

Thank you for any help !

So for example i have Date1 field with values : 012014,012015,012016
and Date2 field with value: 20141005

And i need only Date1 which is at least one year older then Date2 so in this case it will return only 012016

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on, converting them to dates or comparing them as dates?

Comment: Im stuck on converting them to dates so that i can compare them, the comparing part is ok

Comment: Your google search string is `sql server cast string to date`.

Answer (score 3):

I make two `cte`s to show how to work it out. I assume `MMYYYY` are stored as `nvarchar` or `varchar` and `YYYYMMDD` are the same type. If not - you will need one/few conversions on `YYYYMMDD` field.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT '012016' as MMYYYY
UNION ALL
SELECT '022016'
), cte2 AS (
SELECT '20160101' AS YYYYMMDD 
UNION ALL
SELECT '20160202'
)

SELECT *
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN cte2 c2
ON YYYYMMDD LIKE RIGHT(MMYYYY,4)+LEFT(MMYYYY,2) +'%'
```

Output:

```
MMYYYY  YYYYMMDD
012016  20160101
022016  20160202
```

**EDIT:**

To find out differences in years use this:

```
DATEDIFF(year,CAST(YYYYMMDD as date), CAST(RIGHT(MMYYYY,4)+LEFT(MMYYYY,2)+'01' as date))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert both fields into type `DATE`, then compare them.

For `MMYYYY`, you can use the function [`DATEFROMPARTS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) to build a date. For example, convert `012014` into date:

```
-- DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, day)
DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT('012014', 4), LEFT('012014', 2), 1)
```

For `YYYYMMDD`, it is easier, because this is the format ISO with [Time Style 112](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_4). You can use the [`CONVERT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function to do the conversion :

```
CONVERT(DATE, '20141005', 112)
```

---

And here's how the final query looks like :

```
WITH casted AS (
    SELECT
        DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(date1, 4), LEFT(date1, 2), 1) AS d1,
        CONVERT(DATE, date2, 112) AS d2,
        -- ...
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM casted
WHERE d1 <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
column1 is stored MMYYYY format and column2 is stored YYYYMMDD.

```
where column1=  case when datepart(month,taskDuedate)>9 then convert(varchar,datepart(month,taskDuedate))else '0'+convert(varchar,datepart(month,taskDuedate))end+convert(varchar,datepart(year,taskDueDate))
```